# How to use "Self.attr" in a KeyPath?

Tags: swift, core-data, keypaths

I'm trying to use "Self.displayOrder" in a protocol extension, but it raises the following error "Thread 1: Fatal error: Could not extract a String from KeyPath Swift.ReferenceWritableKeyPath"

Here's the code

```
protocol Listable where Self: NSManagedObject {
    static func sortedFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Self>
    var displayOrder: Int { get set }

}

extension Listable {
    static func sortedFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Self> {
        let req: NSFetchRequest<Self> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: String(describing: Self.self))
        req.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Self.displayOrder, ascending: true)]
        return req
    }
}

final class OwnerModel: NSManagedObject, Identifiable, Listable {
    @NSManaged var displayOrder: Int
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the protocol with `@objc`:

```swift
@objc protocol Listable where Self: NSManagedObject {
    var displayOrder: Int { get set }
}
```

This will tell the compiler to use the Objective-C runtime when processing the keypath, and will allow the conversion from a Swift `KeyPath` to the string needed by `SortDescriptor`.

One note, `sortedFetchRequest` had to be removed from the protocol definition, as default implementations for protocol requirements is not possible in the protocol is @onjc, since default implementation is statically dispatched, while an @objc protocol is dinamically dispatched. This doesn't prevent you from using the default implementation, though, in Swift code.